# Change old dynamic urls to new format with 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

can anyone help me to change old dynamic url format to new dynamic url format?

To be precise i need to change underscores _ to hyphens - in the url, but with 301 redirect
redirect in htaccess, like:

- example.com/posts/22_keyword/33_this_is_the_example_of_old_url.html

I want it to be:

- example.com/posts/22-keyword/33-this-is-the-example-of-old-url.html

I know how to change it in php, but i need to make it work with 301 redirect from old url format to new
in htaccess so i dont lose rankings on google.

Here is the current htaccess info:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html   index.php?view=showad&adid=$7&cityid=$1 [QSA]
```

that convert to:

- posts/3_keyword/6_keyword/235530_this_is_the_example_of_old_url.html

I am not familiar with mod rewrite and I guess this one is kind of easy for someone who have knowledge about it because
all is need to do is to change from _ to -

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive rule to convert `_` to `-`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# using internal rewrites replace all _ by -
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_(.+?\.html)$ $1-$2 [NC,DPI,E=underscores:1]

# one final redirect to change URL in browser 
RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} =1
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser and what error did you get?